# Insert emails into multidimensional array

Tags: php, email, multidimensional-array, imap

I have been assigned a task by my boss to read emails from a gmail inbox and put them into their own divs using php. Receiving the emails is easy enough, however I am struggling with the simple matter of putting each messages details into an array.

I need this array to hold each email's:
From
Subject
Message
The code used to get the emails is:

```
/* connect to gmail */
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$imapPath = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'redacted';
$password = 'redacted';
/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
        if($emails) 
        {
                /* begin output var */
                $output = '';

                /* put the newest emails on top */
                rsort($emails);
                $emailArray = array();
                /* for every email... */
                $t = 1;
                foreach($emails as $email_number) 
                {
                    $temp = array();
                    $t++;
                    if($t == 3)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                        /* get information specific to this email */
                        $overview = imap_headerinfo($inbox,$email_number);
                        if(substr($overview->subject, 0, 1) == '#')
                        {
                            $from = $overview->from[0]->personal;
                            $subject = $overview->subject;
                            $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number, 2);
                            $formattedMessage = imap_qprint($message);
                            $temp = array('from'=>$from, 'subject'=>$subject, 'message'=>$formattedMessage);

                            foreach($temp as $i => $i_val)
                            {
                                $emailArray[$i][] = $i_val;
                            }
                        }
                }
        } 

        /* close the connection */
        imap_close($inbox);
```

Now when I try to fetch the emails out of the array like:

```
$emailArray['from'][0]
```

It will work but using

```
$emailArray['from'][1]
```

won't.
I know for a fact there are two emails that are fetched because I ran the script on a different page and just output the values as they came and it showed 2.

Comment: say `var_dump($emailArray);` to be sure about size of array

Comment: basic debugging: `var_dump($emailArray)`. see what's really in there.

Comment: That is where it's weird. Only the second email is there so it's like it's overwriting the first. This is the same code as the page that received two emails and that $t variable also tracks times through the loop and it hits 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop work one time.

Try this :

```
$t = 0;
```

Because :

```
foreach ($emails as $email_number) {
    $temp = array();
    $t++; 
    //now $t = 2 and it's the first loop.
    if ($t == 3) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Or you can try this :

```
foreach ($emails as $email_number) {
        $temp = array();

        if ($t == 3) {
            break;
        }
        $t++; 
    }
```

Or this :

```
foreach ($emails as $email_number) {

            $temp = array();
            $t++; 
            if ($t == 4) {
                break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Changing $t to 0 works to get both emails but I also get this notice: Notice: Unknown: Invalid quoted-printable sequence: ="ltr">This is a test message<br></div> (errflg=3) in Unknown on line 0 This is a test message is the body of an email

Comment: Could your edit you post and add the code where "This is a test message" is ?

Answer (score 2):

Check $t - it is initialised as 1 then is incremented to 2 on the first email it reads, meaning by the time it reads the 2nd email $t=3 and it breaks out of the loop.

Try changing $t=1 to $t=0 and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: see my comment above please